# ecommerce Book and Bookstore table design logic

Tags: database, database-design, logic

There is a `Book` table that is always unique with title, edition, and author.
And I want all `bookstores` to add their books, but different bookstores can have the same book with different pricing. So I come up with this table design.

[image]

So when one bookstore tries to add a book and the book is already been added by **another bookstore** the current bookstore should have to just fill in the **pricing detail**, not including the **book detail**.
The problem with this is, what if the book detail already been added has some missing or incorrect info? in this case, the current bookstore can flag and moderators or admins can fix it.

**Is there any better way to achieve this?** I don't comfortable with this design logic at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your design makes sense.  You want to keep the "static" information in 1 table, and link "dynamic" information like you did.

Your other question is related to data integrity.  You can put "not null" conditions on fields to ensure all fields are filed, but garbage entries are always possible.  This is a universal problem.

Potential solutions to mitigate this:

- any and all data that can be selected instead of typed in should be linked via another table.  Ex:

  ```
  BookGenre
    bookgenreid PK
    genre       CHAR

  Book
    bookid PK
    genre  FK, BookGenre.bookgenreid
    ...
  ```

  So you store all possible genres in a separate table, so your users cannot invent new genres or mistype values.  Same for authors, countries, ...  This makes it easier to build queries as well and avoid things like [ SciFi, Science Fiction, Sciance fiction, ... ]
- not everyone should be able to enter new books in the system.  Ex. when I worked at a wholesale distributor, only a select group employees could create new products in the database, and they had established a convention on how to do it.  They worked closely with purchasing and receiving.  You will need to dedicate "data administrators".

So try to control as much as you can in the database and - or the application.  Avoid free text fields as much as possible, as users will always think of new ways to mess it up.  Ex. at work currently we have a HUGE project to standardise addresses between unlinked systems.  It is a enormous undertaking, which involves AI.  All this only because no 2 persons enter addresses exactly the same.